# python multiprocessing sleep between executions

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have a python script which is supposed to run multiple jobs in parallel. I set the maximum processes to 20 but I need the script to sleep 5 second between sending the jobs.
So here is my sample code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import multiprocessing
import subprocess


def prcss(cmd):
    sbc = subprocess.call
    com = sbc(cmd, shell='True')
    return (com)


if __name__=='__main__':

    s = 'sleep 5'
    cmd= []
    for j in range(1,21):
        for i in range(10):
            sis = "nohup ~/mycodes/code > str(j)"+"/"+"out"+str(i)+".dat"
            cmd.append(sis)
            cmd.append(s)

    pool=multiprocessing.Pool(processes=20)
    pool.map(prcss,cmd)
```

Although I have sleep 5 in between the 'sis' commands, when I run my script all jobs start immediately. I need to have sleep in between the 'sis' commands as the output from each job depends on the computer clock. So ff I run 20 jobs, they all start with the same system clock and hence they all will have the same output.

Any idea how to have my script to sleep in between the 'sis' commands?

Abedin

Comment: I just noticed that this question is almost an exact duplicate of one you already posted. Please remove one of the two posts to eliminate the duplicate.

Comment: Sorry about that! Done, I removed the duplicate question!

Comment: Thanks for removing the duplicate. BTW, I added the Python tag to your question so the syntax highlighting is applied, and it shows that you're missing a closing quotation mark somewhere in your `sis = ` string.

Comment: I've added a note about string construction to my answer that you may be interested in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the [docs for pool.map()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map). When you create a list of items and then submit them to the pool using map, all of the jobs are submitted to the pool together. Since you have 20 worker processes, 20 of your jobs will start (effectively) all at once. That includes both your `sis` commands and the sleep commands. There's not even a guarantee that they will be executed and complete in the same order, just that you'll receive the results in the same order. The [apply_async()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.apply_async) function might be better for you, because you can control when jobs are submitted to the pool.

It sounds to me like you want your Python script to wait 5 seconds before you issue a `sis` command anyway, so there's no reason you should need to execute the sleep command in a worker process. Try refactoring into something like this:

```
import multiprocessing
import subprocess
import time

def prcss(cmd):
  # renaming the subprocess call is silly - remove the rename
  com = subprocess.call(cmd, shell='True') 
  return (com)

if __name__=='__main__':

  pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=20)
  results_objects = []

  for j in range(1,21):
    for i in range(10):
      sis = 'nohup ~/mycodes/code >'+str(j)+'/'+'out'+str(i)+'.dat'

      # make an asynchronous that will execute our target function with the
      # sis command
      results_objects.append(pool.apply_async(prcss, args=(sis,))
      # don't forget the extra comma in the args - Process must receive a tuple

      # now we pause for five sections before submitting the next job
      time.sleep(5)

  # close the pool and wait for everything to finish
  pool.close()
  pool.join() 

  # retrieve all of the results
  result = [result.get() for result in results_objects]
```

One other note: since the syntax highlighting was applied, it's easy to see that you're missing a closing quotation in your `sis` string, and probably a '+' too. Instead of manually constructing your string, consider using [string.format()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format):

```
sis = 'nohup ~/mycodes/code > {}/out{}.dat'.format(j, i)
```

If the backslash is there to separate path hierarchies, you should use [os.path.join()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join):

```
import os
sis = os.path.join('nohup ~/mycodes/code > {}'.format(j), 'out{}.dat'.format(i))
```

First string generated (in either case) will be:

> nohup ~/mycodes/code > 1/out0.dat

Comment: Once again, @skrrgwasme thank you so much for your suggestion using string formatting. As, perhaps you can see I am pretty new to Python and lack a nice code formatting.
I wish I knew your email so if I am trouble could contact you as you seem to know a lot of stuff about python.

In particular, I really liked your elegant solution to my problem.

Comment: NP. Everyone has to start somewhere. You should checkout [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to get some feedback on your code sometime. Make sure you read their FAQ before asking questions (they only accept working code - no debugging help), but they can provide good feedback on code formatting and give tips for making code more idiomatic.